# can we use some of the arguments of cor with other statistics like RMSE?

Tags: r, correlation

In `cor` function , there is a wonderful argument the " use "(e.g. : use="na.or.complete" )

I tried to use the same argument with calculating RMSE or bias. It seems that it is not working.I wonder what we could use instead.

```
RMSE <- function(x, y){
sqrt(mean((x-y)^2))}
RMSE(x,y, use = "na.or.complete")
Error in RMSE(x,y, use = "na.or.complete") : 
unused argument(s) (use = "na.or.complete")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mean function to compute THE RMSE has an `na.rm` argument, You can use it like this :

```
RMSE <- function (pred,obs,na.rm=FALSE){
   sqrt(mean((pred - obs)^2, na.rm = na.rm))
}
```

The na.rm argument can be used to mimic na.or.complete behavior since in almost cases , using na.or.complete option is equiavlent to remove NA value from the original pairs. For example :

```
swM <- swiss[,1:2]
swM[1,2] <-  NA 
swM[1,1] <-  NA 
identical(cor(swM, use = "na.or.complete"),
          cor(na.exclude(swM), use = "all"))
TRUE
```

With RMSE

```
swM[1,2] <-  NA 
swM[1,1] <-  NA 
identical(RMSE(swM[,1],swM[,2],na.rm=T),
          RMSE(swM[,1],swM[,2],na.rm=F))
 FALSE
```

**EDIT** set very small values to NA

I don'know how you store your data. But I assume you have a data.table with a variable x. You can do something like this :

```
 dat$x[dat$x <= -3.4e+38] <- NA
```

Comment: @Barry No. You should not have the same result. see my example.

Comment: @Barry you misunderstand NA. NA in R for missing values but -3.400000e+38 is ugly but it exists, is not missing. are all you "NA" equal to -3.400000e+38 ?

Comment: This dialog cries out for a reproducible example!

Comment: @agstudy Yes something like that, but not that. In `data.table` it would be `dat[x <= -3.4e+38, x:=NA]` to avoid copying the entire `dat` as `data.frame` would do.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.  The reason you have to quote the `use=` argument to `cor` is that it specifies a character argument used internally to decide between algorithms.  It does not pass a function.  If you type `cor` at the command prompt, you'll see a line:

```
na.method <- pmatch(use, c("all.obs", "complete.obs", "pairwise.complete.obs", 
        "everything", "na.or.complete"))
```

Then a bunch of `if` statements on `na.method`.

You could write your own equivalent, though, by adding a `,use=` argument to your function signature :

```
RMSE <- function(x, y, use="all") {
   if(use=="all") # Do stuff
   if(use=="na.or.complete") # Do other stuff
   sqrt(mean((x-y)^2))
}
```

You could even base your code off of the `cor` code--that's one of the joys of open source software!